# Can you specify a specific version of Composer in the schema?

Tags: php, composer-php

Context: I'm working with a team on PHP projects and we just ran into an issue where a code review from another team member modified the format of the all `time` fields in the `composer.lock` file. It turned out he was using a much older version of composer which output the `time` fields in a different format. Once he updated an re-installed the package, the fields remained the same.

Is there a way to specify a minimum version of Composer to require all team members working on a project to use the minimum version to avoid problems like this. If we hadn't spotted this issue, the `composer.lock` file would have had this unnecessary change happen any time new packages were installed by people with different composer versions

Comment: lock your package versions in composer.json by setting to a specific tag.

Comment: I don't mean locking the package versions. I mean locking the version of Composer itself being used.

Answer (score 3):

You can create script which will be called before each update, and throw exception if composer version is too old.

In `composer.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "ComposerVersionCheck::check"
    ]
}
```

Simple class for version checking:

```
class ComposerVersionCheck {

    public static function check() {
        if (version_compare(\Composer\Composer::VERSION, '1.7.0', '<')) {
            throw new \Exception(
                'Your Composer version (' . \Composer\Composer::VERSION . ') is too old,'
                . ' 1.7.0 or higher is required.'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- either check in `composer.phar` to ensure everyone is using the same version of `composer`
- keep `composer` itself updated at all times to ensure everyone is using the latest version of `composer`, by running `composer self-update`

Regardless, since `composer` changes over time, you would probably still have run into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "composer": "^2.2",
    [...]
}
```

Note: this will prevent `composer update` if <2.2, but not `composer install`, so it will not ensure that Composer is up to date in the deployment servers and team machines, but it will prevent composer.lock from being changed by older versions.